# need best solution for image mapping

Tags: javascript

I would like each letter to play a sound on Click via `onClick`, how can this be done?

[image: A-Z Letters]

Comment: Check if you need to display this as an image. If so, create an image map (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and set clickable areas for each letter. Otherwise create this field by using HTML and CSS. Then just set a JS Click Listener on the letters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on platform you are using, try http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/. It has lots of examples, i think it should help.

Comment: useing image map is ok   only play onclick event embeded is what i need

Comment: Please don't give link-only answers, as the links could become invalid in the future and then the answer would be useless. Try to edit your answer and post at least a summary of what can be found at that link, so that even if the link stops working your answer is still meaningful.